# What is the appropriate SQL method for "Safe to SUM"?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, aggregate

In SQL Server 2008 R2+ we, unfortunately, have some `nvarchar` columns storing numeric data.

In some cases we want to `SUM` the data when it *can* be summed. The problem is that `ISNUMERIC()` returns 1 for a number of entries with are invalid parameters for `SUM`.... I understand what's going on here but I am looking for a workaround.

For example `ISNUMERIC('10,1') = 1` but I cannot include that value in a `SUM` so I would like that value excluded from the `SUM`... and any data points, in fact, which cannot be parameters to `SUM` without being massaged...

So I'm wondering what is the preferred way to determine whether or not the contents of an alphanumeric column *can* be summed?

**EDIT:** It's worth noting that this is a take-off from this answer on SO:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15833014/369775

but I am not convinced that the methods provided in that answer are optimal. I **do** agree with HLGEM:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/338292/369775

> The best solution would be to stop storing integers in a varchar column. Clearly there is a data issue where the data is interpretable as a numeric but cannot be cast as such.

Comment: So do you want 10,1 included in the calculation as 10.1, or do you want it excluded? Do you only want integers to be considered? Are you going to fix the schema?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I want 10,1 excluded. In fact, I want all data points excluded which will cause `SUM` to fail without being manipulated. If there was a regional setting enabled which permitted `10,1` to be a valid parameter for `SUM` then I **would** want it included.

Comment: I ran into a [similar situation](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5312/conversion-of-varchar-data-to-datetime-failing) and Aaron's suggestion led me to staging valid data into a temporary table and then querying from there since I could not ensure the optimizer would approach it the same every time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The challenge with relying on `ISNUMERIC()` for this is that it can look at a lot of data that can't be summed and give it a pass. It isn't `IS_ELIGIBLE_FOR_SUM()` - it is merely returning true if the input could be converted to *any* of the numeric types. Commas are allowed because conversion to `MONEY`, for example, works successfully:

```
SELECT CONVERT(MONEY,'11,2');
```

So this also works:

```
SELECT SUM(CONVERT(MONEY,'11,2'));
```

Which probably isn't what you want. I think it would be safer to replace commas with periods before attempting to perform operations, or just exclude them and filter out rows this way:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(n NVARCHAR(32));

INSERT @t VALUES(N'11,2'),(N'32'),(N'-32.4'),(N'32323'),(N'^'),(N'.'),(N'-');

SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(n) = 1
    AND n NOT LIKE '%[^0-9.-]%' THEN CONVERT(MONEY,n) END)
  FROM @t
  WHERE ISNUMERIC(n) = 1 AND n NOT LIKE '%[^0-9.-]%';
```

The reason you have to perform a `CASE` expression in addition to the filter is that you can't control how the optimizer will process the statement - without `CASE` it might try to perform the conversion before the filter.

Of course, the smartest course of action would be to stop using the wrong data type in the first place. If you continue storing dirty data in ill-advised data types, you don't really get to complain about "optimal"...

Comment: Good answer but what happens when my field is '^' or '-' or '.' ?

Comment: @Matthew did you try them? They don't break my example (I added all three values). Now, something else like `2.4.5` will (and some of those values may have a different impact on calculations like `AVG` because they may pass the filter but are treated as `0`). But I still go back to the end of my answer: use the right data type, and this data won't get in there in the first place. If that's not possible, then at least try to prevent bad data from getting into your wrong data type. If that's not possible, extend the filter to cover other bad data...

Comment: it now works with '.' and '-' since you updated to `CONVERT(MONEY,n)` from `CONVERT(DECIMAL` In the case of `2.4.5` I can still use `ISNUMERIC` so, perhaps, a combination of the two is a good answer here

Comment: @Matthew sorry, I did not mean to change the destination type silently. I started with MONEY, copied the code from my VM, and changed it to DECIMAL afterward. When I added the additional input values the script still had MONEY, I copied and pasted and brought it back.